# What database are better for store and search key/value pair data?

Tags: database, nosql, relational-database, key-value

I need to build a app that your main purpose is to store and search key/value data. What type of database are for that purpose?

Or taking into consideration that all databases are for the purpose of storing and searching data, what type of database can fit better in purpose to store and search key/value data? NoSql? Relational?

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out, a NoSQL database is more suitable for your application than a relational database.

You might want to look into [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Answer (score 2):

You should use NoSQL. There is no point in using relational database when you have no relations whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve; you may even use text files (no joke!).

Comment: but search in text files will not be so optimized, what are you think?